# How to replace all values in selected columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I was trying to figure out a way to transform all values in selected columns of my dataset using an equation $$x_i = x_{max} - x_i$$ using dplyr. I'm not sure how to correctly do this for one column, let alone multiple columns. My attempt at mutating 1 column:

`df1 <- df %>% mutate(column1 = replace(column1, ., x = max(column1) - x)`

My x = max(column1) - x part is not literal, I just want to know how I can implement that equation into all row entries in the column. Furthermore, how can I do this for multiple columns in the same line? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If it is to replace all values `across` multiple columns, loop `across` the `numeric` columns and subtract the values from its `max` value for that column

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ max(., na.rm = TRUE) - .))
```

Comment: When I wanted to change columns x, y, z, I tried ```df <- df %>% mutate(across(c(x, y, z), ~ max(., na.rm = TRUE) - .))``` but it didn't seem to change any values.

Comment: @js2822 You haven't provided a reproducible example.  With a reproducible example `data(mtcars); mtcars <- mtcars %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ max(., na.rm = TRUE) - .)); head(mtcars)` does changes the values.